# code does not work outside jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yurik417/VVvDV/70) code that I'd like to use on my page.

I copied `css` and put it into `<style>` tag on my page. Then I separate part that starts with

```
$(function(){
    $('.anyClass').liEqualizer({
```

and put it into `custom.js`. And the first part that starts with `(function ($) {` I put into `audio_frequency.js`. I added its imports to `head` tag. The page looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <style>
            .sampleWrap { 
                margin-left: 6%;
                margin-top: 5%;
            }
            .eqCol {
                width: 80px;
                margin: 0 0 0 2px;
                float: left;
            }
            .eqItem { 
                height: 20px; 
                width: 100%; 
                background: transparent; 
                margin: 1px 0 0 0; 
                opacity: 0;
                box-shadow: 15px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
            }
            .eqCol .eqItem:last-child {
                opacity:1 !important
            }
        </style>
        <script src="jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="audio_frequency.js"></script>
        <script src="custom.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="sampleWrap d-flex">
            <div class="anyClass"></div>
                <div style="clear:both; padding:15px 0">
                    <button class="start">start</button>
                    <button class="stop">stop</button>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`custom.js` looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.anyClass').liEqualizer({
        row:7,          
        col:20,         
        speed:20,       
        freq:400,       
        on:true 
    });
    $('.start').click(function(){
        $('.anyClass').liEqualizer('start');
        return false;   
    })
    $('.stop').click(function(){
        $('.anyClass').liEqualizer('stop');
        return false;   
    })
});
```

and `audio_frequency` looks like this

```
(function ($) {
    var methods = {
        init: function (options) {
            var p = {
                row: 7,         
                col: 6,         
                speed: 20,      
                freq: 400,  
                on: true        
            };
            if (options) {
                $.extend(p, options); 
            }
            var eqWrap = $(this).addClass('eqWrap');
            for (c = 0; c < p.col; c++) {
                var eqColEl = $('<div>').addClass('eqCol').appendTo(eqWrap); 
                for(r = 0; r < p.row; r++){
                    $('<div>').addClass('eqItem').appendTo(eqColEl);    
                }
            }
            var 
            eqCol = $('.eqCol', eqWrap),
            eqItem = $('.eqItem', eqWrap),
            randomNumber = function (m, n){
                m = parseInt(m);
                n = parseInt(n);
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * (n - m + 1)) + m;
            },
            eqUp = function(colEl, val) {
                var 
                    speed = p.speed,
                    v = p.row - val,
                    i = p.row,
                    j = 0,
                    flag2 = true,
                    eachItemUp = function(){
                        $('.eqItem', colEl).eq(i - 1).nextAll().stop().css({ opacity:'1' });
                        if ($('.eqItem', colEl).eq(i - 1).css('opacity') == 1) { flag2 = false } 
                        else { flag2 = true }
                        $('.eqItem', colEl).eq(i - 1).stop(true).animate({ opacity:'1' }, p.speed, function() {
                            if ($('.eqItem', colEl).index(this) == v) {
                                if(flag2) {
                                    eqDown(colEl,val);
                                }
                            } else {
                                i--;
                                j++;
                                if(i>v){
                                    eachItemUp()    
                                }
                            }
                        })  
                    }
                eachItemUp()
            },
            eqDown = function(colEl,val){
                var 
                    v = p.row - val,
                    i = (p.row-val),
                    j = 0,
                    speed = p.speed * 2,
                    eachItemDown = function(){
                        if (i == (p.row - val)) {
                            $('.eqItem', colEl).eq(i).animate({ opacity:'0' }, speed * 10)
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                i++;
                                j++;
                                if(i < p.row){
                                    eachItemDown();
                                }       
                            }, speed)
                        } else {
                            $('.eqItem', colEl).eq(i).animate({ opacity:'0' }, speed, function(){
                                i++;
                                j++;
                                if(i < p.row){
                                    eachItemDown();
                                }   
                            })
                    }
                }
                eachItemDown();
            },
            eqInterval = function(){
                eqCol.each(function(){
                    eqUp($(this), randomNumber(0, p.row))   
                })
            }
            eqInterval()
            if (p.on) {
                var eqIntervalId = setInterval(eqInterval, p.freq)
                $(this).data({
                    'eqIntId': eqIntervalId,
                    'eqInt': eqInterval,
                    'freq': p.freq,
                    'on': p.on
                })
            } else {
                $(this).data({
                    'eqIntId':eqIntervalId,
                    'eqInt':eqInterval,
                    'freq':p.freq,
                    'on':p.on
                })
            }
        }, start: function () {
             if (!$(this).data('on')) {
                $(this).data('eqInt')();
                var eqIntervalId = setInterval($(this).data('eqInt'), $(this).data('freq'));
                $(this).data ({
                    'eqIntId':eqIntervalId,
                    'on':true
                })
            }
        },
        stop: function () {
            if($(this).data('on')) {
                clearInterval($(this).data('eqIntId'));
                $('.eqItem', $(this)).animate({opacity:0})
                $(this).data({
                    'on':false
                })
            }
        }
    };
    $.fn.liEqualizer = function (method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' in jQuery.liEqualizer does not exist');
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

But when I load page I get

```
TypeError: $(...).eq(...).nextAll(...).stop is not a function[Learn More]
```

What is the problem? Is it trying to evaluate something before all the components are ready on the page?

Comment: don't use jsfiddle, if it confuses you - you can get simple sandbox server for $4 a mo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `$(...).eq(...).nextAll(...).stop` error is because of jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js this ist not complete.

> **Note:**
>   In the jquery.slim.js, the following functions of code are removed:
>
> 1. jQuery.fn.extend
> 2. jquery.fn.load
> 3. jquery.each // Attach a bunch of functions for handling common AJAX events
> 4. jQuery.expr.filters.animated
> 5. ajax settings like jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr, jQuery.ajaxPrefilter, jQuery.ajaxSetup, jQuery.ajaxPrefilter, jQuery.ajaxTransport,
>      jQuery.ajaxSetup
> 6. xml parsing like jQuery.parseXML,
> 7. animation effects like jQuery.easing, jQuery.Animation, jQuery.speedIn the jquery.slim.js, the following function of code are removed:

Here is the complete code, you need `jquery` lib 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>`

```html
<style>
    /*Layout css*/
  
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    text-align: center
  }
  
  .sampleWrap {
    height: 290px
  }
  /*plugin css*/
  
  .eqWrap {
    margin: -1px 0 0 -2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block; //display:inline; //zoom:1;}
    .eqCol {
      width: 37px;
      margin: 0 0 0 2px;
      float: left;
    }
    .eqItem {
      height: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      background: #e7aa3b;
      margin: 1px 0 0 0;
      opacity: 0
    }
    .eqCol .eqItem:last-child {
      opacity: 1 !important
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<div class="sampleWrap">
  <div class="anyClass"></div>
  <div style="clear:both; padding:15px 0">
    <button class="start">start</button>
    <button class="stop">stop</button>
  </div>

  <div class="anyClass2"></div>
  <div style="clear:both; padding:15px 0">
    <button class="start2">start</button>
    <button class="stop2">stop</button>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  /*код плагина*/
  (function($) {
    var methods = {
      init: function(options) {
        var p = {
          row: 7, //кол-во столбцов
          col: 6, //кол-во колонок
          speed: 20, //скорость подсветки кубиков
          freq: 400, //частота сигнала
          on: true //включено по умолчанию (true,false)
        };
        if (options) {
          $.extend(p, options);
        }
        var eqWrap = $(this).addClass('eqWrap');
        for (c = 0; c < p.col; c++) {
          var eqColEl = $('<div>').addClass('eqCol').appendTo(eqWrap);
          for (r = 0; r < p.row; r++) {
            $('<div>').addClass('eqItem').appendTo(eqColEl);
          }
        }
        var
          eqCol = $('.eqCol', eqWrap),
          eqItem = $('.eqItem', eqWrap),
          randomNumber = function(m, n) {
            m = parseInt(m);
            n = parseInt(n);
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (n - m + 1)) + m;
          },
          eqUp = function(colEl, val) {
            var
              speed = p.speed,
              v = p.row - val,
              i = p.row,
              j = 0,
              flag2 = true,
              eachItemUp = function() {
                $('.eqItem', colEl).eq(i - 1).nextAll().stop().css({
                  opacity: '1'
                });
                if ($('.eqItem', colEl).eq(i - 1).css('opacity') == 1) {
                  flag2 = false
                } else {
                  flag2 = true
                }
                $('.eqItem', colEl).eq(i - 1).stop(true).animate({
                  opacity: '1'
                }, p.speed, function() {
                  if ($('.eqItem', colEl).index(this) == v) {
                    if (flag2) {
                      eqDown(colEl, val);
                    }
                  } else {
                    i--;
                    j++;
                    if (i > v) {
                      eachItemUp()
                    }
                  }
                })

              }
            eachItemUp()
          },
          eqDown = function(colEl, val) {
            var
              v = p.row - val,
              i = (p.row - val),
              j = 0,
              speed = p.speed * 2,
              eachItemDown = function() {
                if (i == (p.row - val)) {
                  $('.eqItem', colEl).eq(i).animate({
                    opacity: '0'
                  }, speed * 10)
                  setTimeout(function() {
                    i++;
                    j++;
                    if (i < p.row) {
                      eachItemDown();
                    }
                  }, speed)
                } else {
                  $('.eqItem', colEl).eq(i).animate({
                    opacity: '0'
                  }, speed, function() {
                    i++;
                    j++;
                    if (i < p.row) {
                      eachItemDown();
                    }
                  })
                }
              }
            eachItemDown();
          },
          eqInterval = function() {
            eqCol.each(function() {
              eqUp($(this), randomNumber(0, p.row))
            })
          }
        eqInterval()
        if (p.on) {
          var eqIntervalId = setInterval(eqInterval, p.freq)
          $(this).data({
            'eqIntId': eqIntervalId,
            'eqInt': eqInterval,
            'freq': p.freq,
            'on': p.on
          })
        } else {
          $(this).data({
            'eqIntId': eqIntervalId,
            'eqInt': eqInterval,
            'freq': p.freq,
            'on': p.on
          })
        }
      },
      start: function() {
        if (!$(this).data('on')) {
          $(this).data('eqInt')();
          var eqIntervalId = setInterval($(this).data('eqInt'), $(this).data('freq'));
          $(this).data({
            'eqIntId': eqIntervalId,
            'on': true
          })
        }
      },
      stop: function() {
        if ($(this).data('on')) {
          clearInterval($(this).data('eqIntId'));
          $('.eqItem', $(this)).animate({
            opacity: 0
          })
          $(this).data({
            'on': false
          })
        }
      }
    };
    $.fn.liEqualizer = function(method) {
      if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
      } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
      } else {
        $.error('Метод ' + method + ' в jQuery.liEqualizer не существует');
      }
    };
  })(jQuery);
  /*инициализация плагина*/
  $(function() {
    $('.anyClass').liEqualizer({
      row: 7, //кол-во столбцов
      col: 6, //кол-во колонок
      speed: 20, //скорость подсветки кубиков
      freq: 400, //частота сигнала
      on: true //включено по умолчанию (true,false)
    });
    $('.start').click(function() {
      $('.anyClass').liEqualizer('start');
      return false;
    })
    $('.stop').click(function() {
      $('.anyClass').liEqualizer('stop');
      return false;
    })

    $('.anyClass2').liEqualizer({
      row: 7, //кол-во столбцов
      col: 6, //кол-во колонок
      speed: 20, //скорость подсветки кубиков
      freq: 400, //частота сигнала
      on: false //включено по умолчанию (true,false)
    });
    $('.start2').click(function() {
      $('.anyClass2').liEqualizer('start');
      return false;
    })
    $('.stop2').click(function() {
      $('.anyClass2').liEqualizer('stop');
      return false;
    })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The OP has the library in the source code `<script src="jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>` Also the error would show `$` in not defined way before `$(...).eq(...).nextAll(...).stop` is executed. Unless you mean use a different version of their library?

Comment: I don't know waht have you in `jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js` file,  but   
  `$` not difined means jquery not found

Comment: That's exactly my point. The OP isn't getting that error so the library is clearly loading. Also, I'm not the person who posted the question.

Comment: @FerhadOthman I have...jquery there? I mean I am using that file for other things and everything worked fine - downloaded it from `jquery` website. Though I presume something was deleted in newer version of jquery...

Comment: @FerhadOthman so I guess I have to workaround it as `slim` exist and there might be a reason to remove this functions

Comment: Sometimes you don’t need ajax, or you prefer to use one of the many standalone lib that focus on ajax requests. And often it is simpler to use a combination of CSS and class manipulation for all your web animations. Along with the regular version of jQuery that includes the ajax and effects modules, we’ve released a “slim” version that excludes these modules. The size of jQuery is very rarely a load performance concern these days, but the slim build is about 6k gzipped bytes smaller than the regular version – 23.6k vs 30k. https://blog.jquery.com/2017/03/20/jquery-3-2-1-now-available/

Comment: so these functions like `fn.load` and `fn.extend` are available in other libraries?